# Slow Internet Connection on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS with driver : rtw_8821ce

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, kernel, internet

I have an issue with my internet connection while using WiFi. My computer brand is HP using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS with kernel 5.15.0-52-generic. Currently the speed of the internet is always below 8 Mbps, while other devices always above 20 Mbps. Below is the information related to my laptop. I really hope someone can help me to resolve this slow connection issue.

```
    lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net && iwconfig
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:884d]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce
    Kernel modules: rtw_8821ce, 8821ce
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device [2646:5010] (rev 03)
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"XXXX"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: 60:D7:55:7C:5F:D4   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=27/70  Signal level=-83 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:2882   Missed beacon:0

uname -r
5.15.0-52-generic

    lsmod | grep 8821
8821ce               2068480  0
rtw_8821ce             16384  0
rtw_8821c              94208  1 rtw_8821ce
rtw_pci                28672  1 rtw_8821ce
rtw_core              286720  2 rtw_8821c,rtw_pci
cfg80211              970752  3 rtw_core,mac80211,8821ce

sudo dkms status
[sudo] password for x: 
rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1: added
rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

Thank you very  much in advance for whomever gives their efforts to help. I have been searching for information and troubleshooting for almost 3 days now before deciding to post this question. Feel free to ask for additional information if needed.

[Image of additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYKA4.png)

Result for

```
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
Deleting module version: 5.5.2.1
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-50-generic 5.15.0-52-generic
Building initial module for 5.15.0-50-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rtl8821ce-dkms.
0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-50-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rtl8821ce-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtl8821ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned e
rror exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rtl8821ce-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I suggest you open Additional drivers and install what's offered there, `rtl8821ce-dkms` , or in terminal, `sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms`.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have updated the additional drivers screenshot and result for ``sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms``

Comment: You're already using, hence the error. Nothing else to do.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the way to solve this.

First, we need to blacklist the rtw88_8821ce by using command below:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then add

> blacklist rtw88_8821ce

to the bottom page of the list. Then press Ctrl+O to save then Ctrl+x to exit

With that driver being blacklisted, we will have no wifi adapter and no wifi will be found. I tried using phone USB tethering to connect to internet, and after run the command below:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rtl8821ce/rtl8821ce-dkms_5.5.2.1-0ubuntu10_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i rtl8821ce-dkms_5.5.2.1-0ubuntu10_all.deb
sudo modprobe rtl8821ce
```

Note: anyone may edit and revise my answer since I am not good in explaining it but I am too happy to know that my slow connection issue was solved.