# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS unstable wifi, while windows on the same condition is stable and fast

Tags: wireless, 22.04, realtek-wireless

Possibly important outputs:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:304b]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce
```

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 00
       serial: 2c:3b:70:2f:0e:a7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=5.19.0-42-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.115 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:66 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcf00000-fcf0ffff
```

The wireless connection signal on Windows is really strong, while on Ubuntu it oscillates. I've tried all the options available here: https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/ and none of them worked. Whenever I test the wifi velocity it gives the same as Windows, but on Ubuntu it sometimes completely falls. It only happens on my router a TP-LINK Archer 7.

Is there a router setting to solve this?

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`. What is your WiFi MTU?  `ip link` will show. WiFi MTU should be 1492, not 1500. Easiest fix is done on your DHCP provider/router. Or, temporarily, `sudo ip link set dev name mtu 1492`
  
where "name" is the interface name you found from `ip link`. For a fuller explanation see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723

Comment: Probable duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438405/slow-internet-connection-on-ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-with-driver-rtw-8821ce Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.